# clojure using map to count the elements a vector of list

Tags: clojure

As you can see my first element is somehow being skipped... at least println thinks it is.

```
(def example [(:1 :1 :1) (:2 :2 :2 :2) (:3 :3)])
(println example)
(defn countEachSequence [vec]
  (println vec)
  (let [varName (count vec)]
   (println varName) 
   )
)
(map #(countEachSequence %) example)
```

Desired output is:
([1 3] [:2 4] [:3 2])

This is naming the group and count the amount of elements in that group.

Answer (score 2):

This seems what you want:

```
(defn count-each-seq [v]
  (map (fn [s] [(first s) (count s)]) v))
```

The above `count-each-seq` function returns a sequence of vector. You can print it later. 
If you run the function in REPL, the result will displayed immediately.

There are three things to say in your code:

- When you write code, you should separate the core logic and presentation (in this case, `println`). And your function should return a value.
- Your parameter `vec` is actually a function name `clojure.core/vec`. Pick other name that doesn't conflict with the existing function name.
- Using dash between word is the clojure (or LISP) convention. So name like `count-each-sequence` instead of camel case.

Comment: how about `(defn count-each-seq [v] (map (juxt first count) v))`

Comment: @noisesmith Wow. Looks more compact.

Comment: it's the same thing, just leveraging `juxt` rather than manually constructing the vector